How to Compile a Multi-Module TAL (Transaction Application Language) Program?
At my workplace, I started to learn TAL recently. I decided to write some simple example applications to get the hang of this language and its environment (TACL, GUARDIAN OS, etc). My current objective is to create a multi-file app.
My "util" file has a function term_write_int, which takes an int and writes it to the terminal:
?NOLIST, SOURCE $SYSTEM.SYSTEM.EXTDECS (
?CLOSE,
?MYTERM,
?OPEN,
?NUMOUT
?WRITE)
?LIST

?section term_write_int
?page "term_write_int" 
!
! Write INT to terminal.
!
PROC term_write_int(num);
INT num;
BEGIN
  INT filenum;
  INT termname[0:11];
  INT length := 11;
  STRING text[0:10];

  CALL NUMOUT (text, num, 10, 11);

  CALL MYTERM (termname);

  CALL OPEN (termname, filenum);
  CALL WRITE (filenum, text, length);
  CALL CLOSE (filenum);
END; !term_write_int

My MAIN file adds 2 numbers together and pass the result to the term_write_int function from, the util file:
?NOLIST, SOURCE $SYSTEM.SYSTEM.EXTDECS (INITIALIZER)
?LIST

?NOLIST, SOURCE =util(term_write_int)

PROC myproc MAIN;
BEGIN
  CALL INITIALIZER;

  INT num1 := 4;
  INT num2 := 7;
  INT sum;

  sum := num1 + num2;

  CALL term_write_int(sum);
END; !MYPROC

Originally I wanted to use the BIND TACL command, but for that, I need to compile the files separatelly, and when I try to compile my MAIN file I get the following error:
No file system DEFINE exists for this logical file name:  =util
How should I resolve this?

When do do:
?NOLIST, SOURCE =util(term_write_int)
You are telling the TAL compiler to look for a TACL DEFINE called "=UTIL".
If you want to do it in this way, you should add the DEFINE to TACL environment before calling the TAL compiler for compiling your main, otherwise you will receive that error "No file system DEFINE exists for this logical file name:  =util"
you can reference your file directly:
?NOLIST, SOURCE $vol.subvol.util(term_write_int)
Or, previously calling the compiler:
ADD DEFINE =UTIL, FILE $VOL.SUBVOL.UTIL
TAL /IN MAIN/ ....

Please review the code formatting in your answer following this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.
Thank you for your contribution :)
